# Make throws "Command not found" when passing a variable

Tags: makefile, parameter-passing, gnu-make

I am using

```
GNU Make 3.82
Built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
```

In the Makefile I have

```
download:
     aws s3 cp s3://$(PATH) .
```

and when doing `make PATH=<a valid location> download` 
it throws the error

```
make[1]: aws: Command not found
```

When debugging this, I noticed that this only happens when `$(PATH)` is being used. When the s3 path doesn't use a variable, the make command works.

What is going on and how can I pass a variable to the make command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PATH` is a system variable which your shell uses to find executables. If you redefine it, `aws` can no longer be found in `PATH`. Use a different variable name.

Comment: Eh, happens to everybody :)